# Retrieve and Place Image From SQL Db to a PictureBox In C# WinFormApp

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2012, picturebox

I want to save and retrieve an image from database and place it in a picturebox in my windows form application.

Does any one have any code for it? and please tell me the data type in SQL that I have to use for storing my image (which one is better, `Varbinary(MAX)` or `Image`?)

this is the code i'm using for taking the image from a PicturBox and making it into a binary and storing it into a `Varbinary(MAX)` in the Database and when I Run The code It says: `Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.`

```
System.IO.MemoryStream mymemory = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
img.Save(mymemory,Pbox.Image.RawFormat);
Byte[] myarray = mymemory.GetBuffer();
```

What should I do? 
If anyone has better code please help me with copying the code here for me
any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. The answer will probably be product specific.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your prior "connection strings" question, the best answer would be to not save the image in that table, only a  reference to it; either by using a filestream table or by a text field containing the file system location.